# limit select based on group

Tags: sql, sql-server

What I have is 2 tables.  table A looks like:

```
actID; jobnumber; actTypeID; completeDate
1;    2000;       3;      2012-09-04
2;    2000;       4;      2012-09-05
3;    2001;       2;      2012-09-10
4;    2001;       4;      2012-09-05
5;    2001;       5;      2012-09-05
6;    2002;       1;      2012-09-12
```

Table B looks like:

```
actTypeID;  actType;  projStatus;
1;     Pick;    Build;
2;     Bid;     Estimate;
3;     PMQC;    QC;
4;     Equipment Test;    QC;
5;     Assembly;    Build;
```

What I need to do is include the `projStatus` and `actType` in this:

```
SELECT jobnumber,
    max(completedate) completedate
FROM tableA
GROUP BY jobnumber
```

without increasing the number of records returned, ie get this set back:

```
jobnumber; actType; projStatus; completedate;
2000;  EquipmentTest; QC;       2012-09-05;
2001;  Bid;           Estimate; 2012-09-10;
2002;  Pick;          Build;    2012-09-12;
```

I'm on SQL server 2005 right now, soon to be 2008.  I feel like I'm missing the trick to this.

Comment: You mean without **decreasing** the number of records?

Comment: No.  Increasing.  I only want those 3, but if you join in TableB on the sample query, it pulls in more than just the record with the latest `completedate`per job.

Comment: Why does 2002 have 2012-09-05 and not 2012-09-12?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT  x.[jobnumber], x.[actType], x.[projStatus], x.[completeDate]
FROM
(
SELECT a.[actID], a.[jobnumber], b.[actType], b.[projStatus], a.[completeDate],
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
     (PARTITiON BY jobnumber ORDER BY [completeDate] DESC ) xx
FROM table1 a
      INNER JOIN table2 b
        on a.[actTypeID]=b.[actTypeID]
) x
WHERE x.xx = 1
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ed47f/3)

Comment: This did it.  Thanks John.  I did not know about ROW_NUMBER, and PARTITION.  I learned new stuff today.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) function

```
select jobnumber, actType, projStatus, completedate from
(
    select *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by jobnumber order by completedate desc) rn 
    from tablea
) v
    left join tableb
        on v.acttypeid = tableb.actTypeID
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select a.jobnumber, b.actType, b.projStatus, a.completedate
from 
(select jobnumber, 
       max(actTypeId) as actTypeId,
group by jobnumber) groupTableA
inner join tableA a ON a.jobNumber = groupTableA.jobNumber AND a.actTypeId = groupTableA.actTypeId
inner join tableB b ON b.actTypeId = a.actTypeId
```